# Login Dialog pops up all the time - Angular Login Page

Tags: angular

I'm creating an application in Angular and it has a login page with username and password.
Whenever I fill in the login and password, a dialog box appears asking for the login and password too, but even if I fill it in and give ok, it reappears every time and I can't log in.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBnul.jpg)
I can only solve this problem when I clear the application's cookies on localhost:4200. When I clean it, I can log into the application and the dialog box does not appear.
What could be done so that this login box no longer appears?

I'm using localStorage in the application to store user information.

this is the method called when I click on the login button and the dialog box appears:

```js
async login(loginData: credentialsDTO) {

    let headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("yourclientid" + ':' + "yourclientsecret")
    });

    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret))
    };

    const requestBody = QueryString.stringify({ ...loginData, grant_type: 'password' })
    console.log('resquest : ', requestBody);
    const result = await this.http.post<any>(`${this.urlLogin}/oauth/token`, requestBody, options).toPromise();

    if (result && result.access_token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('token', result.access_token);
      return true;
    }
    return false;

  }
```

Comment: angularjs != angular. They are 2 very different frameworks. Based on the URL in your image you are likely using angular as angularjs has reached EOL. I have removed the angularjs tag from the question.

Comment: [It's hard to answer a programming question without code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Hi! i added the method called when clicking login button above.